# Correct way to receive json data and write to file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node and trying to request some json data from a server and save to a file. I can receive the data no problem but can't work out how to write to a file once it has received all the data. Do I need a callback or do I need to use http.CreateServer()? Any help with this would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
"use strict";

const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    url: 'url-to-request-data',
    method: 'GET',
    accept: 'application/json',
    json: true,} 
};

// Start the request
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) { 
      return console.log(error); 
  } else {
        var path = "~/jsonfile.json";
        fs.writeFile(path, body);
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The json data is quite large so is `fs.writeFileSync` the best way to go? – [ozzyzig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847482/correct-way-to-receive-json-data-and-write-to-file-using-node-js#comment88698419_50847510)

No. You should create a [Writable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) for large files, that way you're only buffering chunks of data at a time in memory, rather than the entire file at once. [`request()`](https://github.com/request/request#streaming) returns an object that implements the `Stream` interface, so you can simply `.pipe()` it to `fs.createWriteStream()`:

```
'use strict';

const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  url: 'url-to-request-data',
  method: 'GET',
  accept: 'application/json',
  // json: true,
};
var path = '~/jsonfile.json';
var ws = fs.createWriteStream(path);

// Start the request
request(options).on('error', function (error) {
  console.log(error);
}).on('close', function () {
  console.log('Done');
}).pipe(ws);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues.

`fs.writeFile` takes a third argument, a callback function, where it will notify you of any error, which you're getting.

```
fs.writeFile(path, body, err => console.error(err));
```

On *nix systems with that file path, you will get `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`

`~` is a bash expansion, node does not know what to do with it.

use:

```
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');

const filePath = path.join(os.homedir(), 'jsonfile.json');
fs.writeFile(path, body, err => console.error(err));
```

Then you will get `[Object object]` written to `~/jsonfile.json` if that URL returns a `json` as you're clearly requesting one.

You have to solutions:

1. Remove `json: true`
2. Or `fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(body), err => /* ... */)`

---

If you are only writing to a file, the best way to go is using `streams`

```
const filePath = path.join(os.homedir(), 'jsonfile.json');
request(options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
// See link for error handling
```

You can read more about `request` and streams, and how to handle errors in [here](https://github.com/request/request#streaming)

Comment: Thanks for catching the `json: true`, I didn't notice that until I saw that mentioned in your answer. I changed it in mine accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I just used ~/ as I didn't want to write the full file path

Comment: You could also do `path.replace('~', os.homedir())`